# Returning the Color from ViewModel class dynamically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin forms app development, I am trying to return 'Color' from my ViewModel class, but I am facing issue for the same. It works fine while running on Android device, but while running on iOS I get the below error:

```
The name 'Color' does not exist in the current context

The type or namespace name 'Color' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried adding System.Drawing dll in iOS project but error persists, I also updated all components using NuGet.

Snippet of my code:

```
public class Ticket: BaseViewModel
{
    // Property to return

public Color PriorityColor
{
    get
    {
        if( condition ) {
            return Color.Red;
        } else if( condition ) {
            return Color.Black;
        } else {
            return Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms.Color?

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, I was using System.Drawing namespace.